# phone auth Firebase not sending OTP to Flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I have enabled and activated the phone authentication service by Firebase to my flutter app, for android the OTP is received fine after i added the sha256 and implemented the code correctly in flutter.

for IOS i have generated the private key and upload it to firebase app check for IOS "DeviceCheck":

[image]

i have also installed the pods correctly to the IOS build and the app check by firebase dependency exists, actually its fully working for android.

in XCode i have archived and uploaded the build to app store connect, then used TestFlight to test the build, the problem is the whole app is not redirecting to the OTP screen after putting the phone number and clicking in login, here is my implementation for the phone auth using the provider, first after user enter the phone number and clicks login this function triggered:

```
  void sendPhoneNumber() {
    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
    ap.signInWithPhone(context, "+${selectedCountry.phoneCode}$phoneNumber");
  }
```

and this is what happened in the `signInWithPhone()` function:

```
void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted: (phoneAuthCredential) {},
          verificationFailed: (error) {
            throw Exception(error.message);
          },
          codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
            if (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name == '/otp_screen.dart') {
            } else {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => OtpScreen(
                      verificationId: verificationId, phoneNumber: phoneNumber),
                  settings: RouteSettings(name: '/otp_screen.dart'),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {});
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
    }
  }
```

in the main file the app check service is initialized, i'll appreciate any help cause am not sure what is missing.